# Simple logic not working or am I missing something?

Tags: java, logic, logical-operators

I don't understand why the following class prints out:
true
false

I thought the output should be:
false
false

because this line prints false:

```
System.out.println((11 >= 1 || 11 <= 10) & (true == false));
```

so this line should also print false:

```
System.out.println(in1To10(11, false));
```

What am I missing here? Here's the class.

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(in1To10(11, false));

        System.out.println((11 >= 1 || 11 <= 10) & (true == false));

    }

    public static boolean in1To10(int n, boolean outsideMode) {
        if ((n >= 1 || n <= 10) & (outsideMode == false)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your expectation and the result are the same..

Comment: It prints `true false`, and you expected it to print... `true false`? What is the question?

Comment: I ammended my questions. my expected output is false false

Comment: If you want to get matching output, pass `true` to `in1to10` ([demo](http://ideone.com/uJXrMf)).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's decompose the test in in1to10 :

Parameters : outsideMode = false; n = 11;

- (n >= 1 || n <= 10) :=> (11 >= 1 || 11 <= 10) :=> (true || false) :=> so TRUE
- outsideMode == false :=> false == false :=> so TRUE

In the end :

```
public static boolean in1To10(int n, boolean outsideMode) {
    if ((TRUE) & (TRUE)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

:=> return TRUE !

Comment: Nope, in Java, boolean true is `true`. Not `TRUE`.

Comment: In this case we're not talking about exact Java syntax or key words, we're talking of Boolean logic.

Comment: thanks for answering. I will upvote the other answers as well.

Answer (score 2):

You want to test if value is in the range 1 to 10 ?
If thats the case, change (n >= 1 || n <= 10) to (n >= 1 && n <= 10)

Answer (score 2):

```
    (                  true                    )
    (      true       ) & (        true        )
    (true   || false  ) & (        true        )    <--- false == false is true!
if ((n >= 1 || n <= 10) & (outsideMode == false)) {
    return true;
}
```

Look, is `n >= 1`? Yes, so it's `true`. `true v p <-> true`, so Java doesn't even check further. `true /\ true <-> true` so we enter `if`. `return true`;

Your code is in plain English:

```
if ((n is greater or equal to 1 OR smaller or equal 10) AND is the mode set to false)
     return true
```

If you want it to return true if the number is between 1 and 10 incl, it would be:

```
if ((n is greater or equal to 1 AND smaller or equal 10) AND is the mode set to false)
     return true
```

which in Java is:

```
if ((n >= 1 && n <= 10) && (outsideMode == false)) {
    return true;
}
```

Also remember to use `&&` and `||` as they are logical operators instead of `|` and `&` bitwise logical operators when dealing with boolean values.

Comment: I see so Java doesnt even check the & operator?

Comment: It does. It doesn't even check the `||` operator. It's because you have the alternative, so it's true if at least one of arguments is true. n>=1 is true, so it returns true immidiately

Comment: @D.Ace I edited my answer, so it's easier to understand. If you still doesn't understand something, try the change I gave you, see how it works and then ask me further questions. I'll answer asap

Comment: xenteros i see so the || which is a short circuit operation will return true immediately is the first condition is true. I  thought it's only going to short circuit the first equation which is this: (n >= 1 || n <= 10) and not the second equation which is this: (outsideMode == false). so the first equation becomes true and second is false so I ended up with (true, false)  --> which should print false?

Comment: Slow.. The point is, that `(n>=1 || n<=10)` is always `true`. Every number is greater than 1 or smaller then 10! If you want to have numbers from 1 to 10, you want them to be `(n>=1 && n<=10)` You want numbers that are greater or equal 1 and smaller or equal then 10. Both things at the same moment

Answer (score 1):

> so this line should also print false: `System.out.println(in1To10(11, false));`

No, this line should not print `false`. Although the first parameter, `11`, indeed turns the expression `n >= 1 || n <= 10` from your method into `11 >= 1 || 11 <= 10`, which matches your other expression, the second parameter, `false`, turns `outsideMode == false` into `false == false`, while your other expression has `true == false`.

That is why the two outputs are different: the output from `in1To10` is `true` because the comparison `false == false` produces `true`, while the output from `main` is false, because `true == false` produces `false`.

**Note:** your expression does not match its stated goal of checking if `n` is between `1` and `10`, inclusive. You need to replace `||` with `&&` to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed that in function in1to10, you are comparing (false == false) and in main you are comparing (true == false). And so is the result. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This will return `true`. How?

```
    if ((n >= 1 || n <= 10) & (outsideMode == false)) {
        return true;
    }
```

You are passing `11` and `false` to the function.

When it goes to inside the first condition it will check that `n >= 1` mean `11 >= 1` that is `true`, so it will not check `n<=10`. Again it will check the second condition and your `outsideMode` is `false`,

That will be like this, `(true) & (true)`

hence the whole condition will be `true` and the funciton will `return true`.

Again the second condition,

```
 (11 >= 1 || 11 <= 10) & (true == false)
```

It will return `false`. How?

As `11 >= 1` is `true` and again it will not check `11 <= 10`, and right side is `false`.
So the condition will be become like this,
`true & false` that will be `false`.

Comment: thats what I thought @Pirate but its not printing false. It is printing true.

Comment: so you want to return false from the function? change your || to & inside the function and it will return false.

Comment: Ok but in the explanation it's been mention this line will be false: "So the condition will be become like this, true & false that will be false". Is this still correct???

Comment: in the explanation it is (true & true), but if you change || to & it will become (false & true) that will be false.